# Add paragraph fields to a view

Tags: views, paragraphs

I have a content type "view" that has a paragraph attached to it, giving the ability to add a body, image, file, block, etc. I need to create a view for the blog listing that will show the title, thumbnail of image, and the summary for the body. But I guess it's been too long since I've done this, as I can't seem to figure out how to get the paragraph fields added to the view.

I've been searching like crazy, but oddly can't seem to find the answer. Lots on more complex stuff, but not just adding the field. I thought I did a relationship and then added the fields, but I just get an empty result.

We're on Drupal 9.5.11.

Answer (score 2):

Add paragraph field in view through relationship

1. You need to get paragraph reference(Paragraph referenced from 'field_name'in content_type) field that in content type in the relationship
2. After adding relation, when you try to add field it should start display the field that exist in the referenced paragraph